# how to pass subfolder params in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to pass the parameters of a subfolder of a url but I have not been successful. I only get the parameter from url 1 but when trying to get the parameter in url 2 it throws me access forbidden error

url 1 - web.com/folder/param1

url 2 - web.com/folder/subfolder/param1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: could you please do let me know if this has worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure your htaccess is placed along side with `folder` folder(not inside it).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

##2 parameter handling rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]

##1 parameter handling rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA]
```